# Java Android :Send data from one thead to another thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sendmessage

I'm working on Android UI Thread, and there is one time-consuming work, so I put It on another thread. There two thing I want:

1) after this sub-thread run, UI Thread will start to do workA

2)this workA will take some data that create in sub-thread.

Here my solution:

```
Car car;    
public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();   
        Thread t = new Thread(){
                car = new Car();
                car.takePetrol;   //take car full petrol
            }
        });

        t.join();
        count_How_far_Car_can_go(car.getPetrol);
```

}

The problem in my code is: I have use t.join(); to wait thread t finish. And this will "Block" the UI Thread. Of course, that is not what I want. (because I make another thread so UI Thread still can work smoothly)

Who has another solution for my problem, please help me :)

thanks :)

Comment: And, I still trust StackOverFlow Community ...

Comment: The answer below seems to be the way to go with AsyncTask if you want some way to interact with GUI thread.  I personally use standard Java Threads and use the Producer-Mediator-Consumer model to send messages to and from GUI and other threads.  http://jaiswaltraining.com/DesignPatterns/ch13.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out `AsyncTask` class from `android.os.AsyncTask` package.

**EDIT:** Sorry for the quick answer. I have improved it according to OP's needs.

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Car> {
        @Override
        protected Car doInBackground() {
            // Create your Car here
            return car;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Car car) {
            // This will be executed on UI thread after completion
        }
}
```

And trigger it like this

```
MyTask task = new MyTask();
task.execute();
```

If you need to pass parameters to your `AsyncTask`, you can add your parameter object to class definition, and of course pass your parameter object while executing your task.

```
private class MyTaskWithParams extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Car> {
        @Override
        protected Car doInBackground(String parameter) {
            // Create your Car using the String you passed
            return car;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Car car) {
            // This will be executed on UI thread after completion
        }
}
```

With the parameter added to definition, you should instantiate with

```
MyTask2 task2 = new MyTask2();
task2.execute("SomethingSomething");
```

Comment: Seriously? What has that example code got to do with what the OP is asking? If they've never used an `AsyncTask` before, it's only going to confuse things. At least give an `AsyncTask` example that has some relevance to what they're trying to do.

Comment: @MisterSquonk Sorry for the messy copy-paste. I have improved my answer in an understandable fashion.

Comment: Oh. thanks so much :) Before you edit, I must read a long post and hard to understand !!! after this, I read again that post I see more easily.

Answer (score 1):

Use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and put...

```
car = new Car();
car.takePetrol;   //take car full petrol
```

...into the `doInBackground` method. Once that has completed, the `onPostExecute` method is called and you can do 'workA' in there.

Answer (score 0):

`ConditionVariable` & `ExecutorService` is more  suitable for this scene.
 [see here for android blog](http://ihavegotyou.iteye.com/blog/1408434)